# How to generate a JSON string from an Array in RUBY on RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have an issue while generating json object from an Array using ***Ruby on Rails*** (i am just like beginner in this area) ,
I have an array like

questions=  [{
"question_cd": "Question1002",
"value": {
"value": "NO"
}
},
{
"question_cd": "Question30",
"value": {
"value": "NO"
}
}, {
"question_cd": "Question138",
"value": {
"value": "NO"
}
}, {
"question_cd": "Question870",
"value": {
"value": "NO"
}
}, {
"question_cd": "Question1524",
"value": {
"value": "NO"
}
}, {
"question_cd": "Question1781",
"value": {
"value": "NO"
}
}, {
"question_cd": "Question2084",
"value": {
"value": "YES"
}
}
]

**Generate Json string :**

```
 questions. each do |dt|          
        questioncode =  dt&.dig('question_cd')           
        value =  dt&.dig('value')
        questioncode =  dt&.dig('question_cd')           
        value =  dt&.dig('value')
        questiondt = '"'+ questioncode+'": '+'"'+value+'"'
        @finalquestion = questiondt if @finalquestion.blank?
        @finalquestion = @finalquestion+', '+questiondt if !@finalquestion.blank?
     end     
     
     @questions_json = "{ #{@finalquestion} }"
```

using above array i need to generate a JSON object  like

```
{
    "Question1002": "NO",
    "Question30":  "NO",
    "Question138": "NO",
    "Question870": "NO",
    "Question1524": "NO",
    "Question1781": "NO",
    "Question2084": "YES",    
}
```

An this should be return as Json string (in RUBY ON RAILS) like

```
def json_questions
{
 "questionslist" : @questions_json
}
end
```

I am able to get a json string but it added ""  char while return to parent method . Here is the output what i get

```
  { "questionslist": "{ \"Question1002\": \"'NO\",\"Question30\": \"'NO\",\"Question138\": \"'NO\",\"Question870\": \"'NO\",\"Question1524\": \"'NO\",\"Question1781\": \"'NO\",\"Question2084\": \"'NO\"}",
     "Description of Operations": "test description"
                }
```

Please help me how to return JSON string with out ''

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you post the code that you're using to get the JSON string as well as an example of what the desired output would look like?

Comment: Hello @NMPennypacker , I have update my tryout code in " Generate Json string : " section . Sorry i was out last week .

Comment: Hello @NMPennypacker,  solved the problem my self . Now it is working as i expecting the result ..